# how to filter list of categories from a categorical column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
    id      gender  articleType  baseColour  season   usage

0   15970   Men     Shirts       Blue        Fall     Casual
1   39386   Men     Jeans        Blue        Summer   Casual
2   59263   Women   Watches      Silver      Winter   Casual
3   21379   Men     Sport Pants  Black       Fall     Casual
4   53759   Men     Tshirts      Grey        Summer   Casual
```

The `articleType` column has around 60 different categories. I don't want all 60 categories. I want that column to have only these articles:

```
category = ['Tshirts', 'Shirts', 'Casual Shoes', 'Watches', 'Beauty Product', 'Sports Shoes', 'Kurtas', 'Tops', 'accessories', 'Briefs', 'Sport Pants', 'Shorts', 'Formal Shoes', 'Jeans', 'Trousers', 'Kurtis', 'Dresses', 'Sarees', 'Jackets']
```

How do I select only those?

I have done this, `df[(df['articleType'] == category)]`, but it is giving me error. `ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (44077,), (19,))`

Comment: Try : `df[(df['articleType'].isin(category)]`

Comment: It worked @I'mahdi , correction: `df[df['articleType'].isin(category)]` thanks